# How to override a named display on display list - glCallList()

Tags: opengl

About the [glCallList](http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glCallList.html) , assume I have some named display on the display list ,I know that each of them could be re-drawn by calling `glCallList(i)` .

My question is  - is it possible to overwrite this named display ? mean , once the `i'st` is exist  , I will make a display calling and it would be stored at `glCallList(i)` .

**Edit:**

For example  - right now `glCallList(1)` draw a cube  , I want to overwrite it , and make
`glCallList(1)` to draw a triangular .

Comment: Huh, what exactly is it you're wondering about. Your question is confusing...

Comment: I have added an example  , maybe it would be more clear now. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that display lists are among the oldest parts of OpenGL and their use was frowned upon even before they were officially deprecated. The primary purpose they originally served was to "record" sequences of commands that would setup state / data persistently in lieu of modern OpenGL's state/data objects (e.g Texture Objects, Vertex Buffer Objects, Sampler Objects, etc.).

Nevertheless, a pair of calls to `glNewList (...)` and `glEndList (...)` will actually replace a display list rather than allocating a new one if you pass it a handle that already had data. So you do not need to go through the trouble of `glDeleteLists (...)` and then `glGenLists (...)` to reuse the same handle (*name*).